# Assets not install in symfony 4

Tags: symfony, assets, symfony4

I read symfony documentation for [Web Assets](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html) and create `/assets` directory in **root** of my project then run command `php bin/console assets:install` but get:

> [OK] No assets were provided by any bundle.

**I store one CSS file in assets directory** but didn't install in `/public`

how should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web assets documentation for Symfony 4 recommends using Webpack Encore.
The `assets:install` command is not used in this configuration.

Here's what you have to do [according to the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html) :

- Install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/) on your computer.
- Install Encore into your project with : `yarn add @symfony/webpack-encore --dev`
- Configure webpack / Encore by editing (or creating) the `webpack.config.js` file [as described here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html#configuring-encore-webpack).
- Compile your assets by running : `yarn run encore dev`

Comment: and what can i do for images and etc.

Comment: @A.Seddighi
Apparently Webpack / Encore doesn't handle static assets yet. There's a workaround [described here](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/24#issuecomment-352959905) which consists in requiring the files in a javascript file.

Comment: Thank you so much - I test it and check the answer 

Comment: How come there is no a proper solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround to do it clearly (more or less) while we are waiting for further webpack-encore development. Can be done by Makefile or similar way but here is more native solution.

Create blank bundle:

```
// src/BlankBundle/BlankBundle.php
namespace App\BlankBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class BlankBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

Then put your assets to `src/BlankBundle/Resources/public` directory and enable the bundle:

```
// add it to config/bundles.php
App\BlankBundle\BlankBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

After executing `php bin/console assets:install` command your resources will be at `public/bundles/blank` directory.

Comment: I found this solution useful for an API created via ApiPlatform. The ApiPlatform package uses the old technique to copy it's assets, and I have no other need for Encore, so adding this to my src/ allows me to use the few images I need here and there.